# enumerates combined with ranges

Tags: python-3.x

I am just learning Python and am trying to combine a range with an enumerate. I have tried a few things such as:

```
students = ("James","John","Robert","Michael","William","David","Richard","Joseph","Thomas","Charles","Christopher","Daniel","Matthew","Anthony","Donald","Mark","Paul","Steven","Andrew","Kenneth","George","Joshua","Kevin","Brian","Edward","Mary","Patricia","Jennifer","Elizabeth","Linda","Barbara","Susan","Jessica","Margaret","Sarah","Karen","Nancy","Betty","Lisa","Dorothy","Sandra","Ashley","Kimberly","Donna","Carol","Michelle","Emily","Amanda","Helen","Melissa")
print("The gold medal goes to:",students[0])
print("The silver medal goes to:",students[1])
print("The bronze medal goes to:",students[2])
print("All winners in order:")
for index, student in enumerate(students in range(3,51)):
    place=str(index+1)
    print(place,student.title())
```

which gives me an error, and I've tried this:

```
students = ("James","John","Robert","Michael","William","David","Richard","Joseph","Thomas","Charles","Christopher","Daniel","Matthew","Anthony","Donald","Mark","Paul","Steven","Andrew","Kenneth","George","Joshua","Kevin","Brian","Edward","Mary","Patricia","Jennifer","Elizabeth","Linda","Barbara","Susan","Jessica","Margaret","Sarah","Karen","Nancy","Betty","Lisa","Dorothy","Sandra","Ashley","Kimberly","Donna","Carol","Michelle","Emily","Amanda","Helen","Melissa")
print("The gold medal goes to:",students[0])
print("The silver medal goes to:",students[1])
print("The bronze medal goes to:",students[2])
print("All winners in order:")
for index, student in enumerate(students):
    for students in range(3,51):
        place=str(index+1)
        print(place,student.title())
```

Which just prints each name 50 times.
I am just a student so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `for index, student in enumerate(students[3:], 3)`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't need to use `range`. In order to understand what went wrong in your snippets, consider this code:

```
>>> for index, student in enumerate(students):
...     print(index, student)
...
```

This prints:

```
0 James
1 John
2 Robert
...
49 Melissa
```

`enumerate` takes two parameters:

1. The array
2. Optionally, the first number which is to be used as an index (zero if not given).

and it returns two things:

1. the list of all indices of the array (i.e. from zero to `len(your_array)-1`)
2. the array itself

Notice how your first snippet contains `for index, student in enumerate(students in range(3,51)):`, particularly the `students in range(3,51)` expression. Because *that* is not immediately preceded by `for`, instead of looping through the range like you intended it to, it actually treated it as a condition. And since `students` is a tuple in your code, it will *not* be inside `range(3,51)` and this expression will return False. Since you can't call `enumerate(False)`, because False isn't an array, you get the error `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`.

In your second snippet, you loop through the entire enumeration, but each name is actually being printed 48 times (51-3=48) and the reason it's printed so many times is because the inner `for` statement has an `index` and `student` element but it's printing them each time it sets `students` to 3, 4, etc. up to 50 (but not including 51). By the way, don't re-assign `students` here or it will replace your tuple of students with a number.

Instead you should take a slice of the student tuple you need and specify the first index you are interested in printing and pass those as parameters to `enumerate`, so in your case: `enumerate(students[3:], 3)`. In particular, the indexes you print with this will start at three, *not* zero.

Then your code becomes:

```
students = ("James","John","Robert","Michael","William","David","Richard","Joseph","Thomas","Charles","Christopher","Daniel","Matthew","Anthony","Donald","Mark","Paul","Steven","Andrew","Kenneth","George","Joshua","Kevin","Brian","Edward","Mary","Patricia","Jennifer","Elizabeth","Linda","Barbara","Susan","Jessica","Margaret","Sarah","Karen","Nancy","Betty","Lisa","Dorothy","Sandra","Ashley","Kimberly","Donna","Carol","Michelle","Emily","Amanda","Helen","Melissa")
print("The gold medal goes to:",students[0])
print("The silver medal goes to:",students[1])
print("The bronze medal goes to:",students[2])
print("All winners in order:")
for index, student in enumerate(students[3:], 3):
    place=str(index+1)
    print(place,student.title())
```

This prints the expected output:

```
4 Michael
5 William
6 David
...
50 Melissa
```